# memcpy() function usage in C

Tags: c, memcpy

I have a query about using the memcpy() function.I have written the below program, it compiles but doesn't print an output. The .exe opens and the crashes. I am using Code Blocks as my IDE using GNU GCC compiler.

```
int main()
{
    char a[]= "This is my test";
    char *b;
    memcpy(b,a,strlen(a)+1);
    printf("After copy =%s\n",b);
    return(0);
}
```

However, if I change the array *b to b[50] it works!! I don't understand why.

Please provide your suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: memcpy attempts to write to memory `b` points to - which is unknown. `b` is unitialised - it could be anywhere, and there is absolutely no reason to think your program is allowed to write to that memory location.

Comment: As Graham Borland said, your char *b isn't initialized, it's just a single char*, you need to allocate a memory for it by using malloc() and specify it's size, then it'll work.

Comment: @Survaf93 `b` is not a single char, it's a pointer.

Comment: It's a single char* that's what I meant :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pointer `b` is uninitialized. It is pointing to some random location in memory. So when you copy stuff into the memory which `b` is pointing to, bad things are likely to happen.

You need to initialize it; perhaps allocate some memory for it with `malloc()`.

```
char *b = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);
```

And then free it when you're finished.

```
free(b);
```

Comment: Wow!! You guys are really gud!! Thanks for the most perfect answer!! I will mark it answered as soon as I am allowed to!!

Comment: Now since I know the working of this memcpy() function, I would like to use this for the ARM compiler.I am trying to copy the RXed bytes from UART to my SRAM in the stellaris device. I am using the below code but it keeps giving errors!            char mycharacter;
mycharacter = ROM_UARTCharGetNonBlocking(UART0_BASE);
memcpy(SRAM_BASE, mycharacter, size_t (mycharacter);

Answer (score 2):

You are lucky it did not crash when you used pointer - it should have.

When you copy memory, destination must be allocated first. If you use `char b[50]`, you allocate 50 bytes for `b` on stack. If you use `char *b`, you did not allocate anything yet, and typically should do this using something like `malloc` : `b = malloc(50);`.

With malloc it will work, but then you should not forget to release that memory with `free(b);`.

If memory was allocated on stack, release happens automatically.

Comment: It's better if he uses malloc(strlen(a)+1);

Comment: True, but this example is 100% equivalent to `b[50]`

Comment: For this specific situation it will work but don't you think it's better for him/her to understand the functionality of malloc() and memory allocation ?

Comment: Well, I already explained quite a bit about malloc/free here. To understand it really well one needs to read a book or at least `man malloc`, `man free`, `man memcpy`